# How to make alert dialog box to open when there is no department found using Angular2 or Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a department section, if i have no departments found in that then i must get a dialog box saying "No department found". I am here by sharing my HTML and ts code. Please help

HTMl:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <ng-select [options]="departments" (click)="checkDepartment(departments)"  notFoundMsg="No Departments Found" name="department" >
                            </ng-select>
                        </div>
```

Ts:

```
checkDepartment(check){
console.log(check);
console.log(check);
if(check == 0){
   this.dialog.open(Department);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the console.log?

Comment: Thanks for response @David, i had updated consoled output please have a look

Comment: If you just want a dialog when there are no departments found you can add a dialog under a condition of `*ngIf`. Or on the TS class you can use `ngAfterViewInit()` to check if there are any department founds and trigger an event if none are found. [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Can you please edit in my question

Comment: Can you paste the TS related to the current HTML code? Something like this in simple: `<div *ngIf="departments.size === 0">No departments found.</div>`

Comment: ya i will edit in question

Comment: updated the code

Comment: @David: i had updated code please have a look

Comment: Why have you edited your question to remove the code snippets you originally included?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you are already using Bootstrap. There is a [Bootstrap module](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) for Angular. You could use the [Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) here.

In the component where you have the `ng-select` implement `AfterViewInit` and add the `ngAfterViewInit` method. There you can check the department size and if it is empty open the modal.

```
export class PageComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (department.length === 0) {
      // Open modal
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am very bad at javascript too, i will try.. ya i will check and update u

Comment: @Tulsi I don't know you code exactly, it was just a sample for getting the department size.

Comment: ya i will try to do

Comment: i get department from this api, i had updated in my code. should i need to add anything in html?

Comment: @Tulsi You should add the modal itself into the body. There are many examples on the page I linked: [Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

Comment: i had done with the department api, i am getting modal dialog box as soon as page opens but i need that to come when i click on department section

Comment: In that case you don't need the AfterViewInit and just move the modal open to the `checkCampaign()` function then. This way the modal will only open after clicking and after department length is checked.